# Which file to get for old Debian 3.0

Tags: debian

I found [images](https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/3.0_r6/i386/iso-cd/?C=S;O=D) for Debian 3.0 so that I can try run old Debian in Virtual Box. But which file should I get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `debian-30r6-i386-binary-1.iso`

[The CD/DVD/BD fails to boot! / From which disc should I boot?](https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#bootable)

> Only the first CD/DVD/BD in a set is bootable.